# Migrate data between two MOSS 2007 farms

Tags: 2007

We have a farm running a Sharepoint 2007 implementantion that is filled with data, including running workflows.
We have a new version of the sharepoint 2007 site, deployed in a new server farm, and we have to migrate the data between them.

What options would we have for the migration in scenario 1) they are compatible; and in scenario 2) they are not compatible, meaning there are differences in content types, ...?

Any ideas are highly appreciated.
Regards

Comment: What type of "stuff" are you looking to migrate? Content (documents/list items)? Site collections? Lists?

Comment: Several sites (team sites), under the same site collection, and a list that contains a field referencing those team sites. I see we can export a site using the stsadm command, but I'm a bit unsure to what will happen in terms of dependencies the list has, links to docs that may brake, ...

Answer (score 1):

I will recommend you read this [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263037%28office.12%29.aspx) article on moving content databases from one farm to another.

How tricky it will be depends on several things, for example if your SQL server uses aliases or not.

Comment: I don't want to move the complete content database, otherwise I'll move more things than I want. I really just want a specific list and a bunch of team sites that are referenced by that list...

Comment: Metalogix got a nice tool for doing scheduled migrations from one web app to another (site migration manager i think its called). Its not free, but not terribly expensive either. This might be something you can use?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Gary Lapointe's custom STSADM commands:
http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/stsadmpowershell-commands/

I had very good luck moving a large list using the gl-export list command.

Answer (score 0):

Backup the entire old  moss farm sharepoint site collection and restore the new farm sharepoint site collection. if we do backup and restore site collection, the workflow also moved.

Backup
stsadm.exe -o backup -url  -filename

Restore:
stsadm.exe -o restore -url  -filename  -overwrite

Thanks
Ramu

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you look at [Chris O'Brien's Content Deployment Wizard](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/12/introducing-sharepoint-content.html)

This uses the Content Deployment API so has similar options and benefits/drawbacks to using Content Deployment in CA but allows for far more granular data transfer (down to specific file level).

The one thing you may find is a sticking point though is to my knowledge it won't transfer workflows. However I don't think you will be able to do this without restoring the entire content database.